# Moto and boto3 mocks only when specifying the specific python file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, boto3, moto

I'm using moto to mock my aws calls in my unit tests. When i run `pytest tests/test_file.py` the unit test will be successful and boto3 gets mocked.

When i run `pytest tests/` to detect all the test files in the directory, `boto3` doesnt get mocked by moto. Causing an error below.

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the CreateRole operation: The security token included in the request is expired`

Is there a specific flag I need to use in `pytest` to let it act like im running an individual file?

Comment: Moto does not work if the import order is wrong - which could happen if a boto3-client is instantiated in `tests/other_file.py` before the mock is started. Have you read this page? http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html#what-about-those-pesky-imports

Comment: Thanks, i think you've guided me in the right direction, i found problems with another set of unit tests, when they get removed from the tests, my `moto` related tests pass, so there is clearly something messing up the `moto` tests in the other unit tests.